# PHP DOM and single quotes

Tags: php, xml, dom

Is there any way to tell DOMDocument to use single quotes instead of double quotes for attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. DOMDocument is a data-oriented access API for XML. And it serializes the documents however it wants to.

There is no ->save() flag http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php in PHP to accomplish it. And other language bindings don't allow it either: [Can nokogiri use single quotes for attributes on saving xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822922/can-nokogiri-use-single-quotes-for-attributes-on-saving-xml)
And this is because libxml itself does provide no means to override this. `libxml2/xmlsave.h` and others mention no quote-style flags. So, I'm afraid you're really out of luck.

Comment: Indeed. @Ronald, it may be easier to solve the problem of why you require single quotes in the first place...