# Keep entity &apos;

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to keep the entity `&apos;` when I save the document that contains it, but SaveXML() function converts the entity to sign ('), which is equivalent understand that, but I need to keep the entity (`&apos;`). Can anybody help me?

This is the code I have:

```
<?php
    $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        <nodo1>
            <elemento1 descripcion='Mi descripcion mas &apos;'/>
        </nodo1>
    ";
    echo $xml . PHP_EOL;
    $xdoc = new DomDocument();
    $xdoc->loadXML($xml);
    $aux = $xdoc->saveXML();
    echo $aux;
```

And this is the result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<nodo1>
<elemento1 descripcion='Mi descripcion mas &apos;'/>
</nodo1>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nodo1>
<elemento1 descripcion="Mi descripcion mas '"/>
</nodo1>
```

Comment: This isn't possible. But the two documents are equivalent. Why do you need the `&apos;`?

Comment: Because the system for which is the xml says should replace the values & = & amp;, "= & quot; '= & apos; <=" & lt ", and> =" gt ".

Comment: I read that if the value of an item is between (") could then use ('), but was looking to see if there is way to replace the (") to &apos.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP DOM and single quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473520/php-dom-and-single-quotes)

Answer (score -1):

Change it to this

```
<elemento1 descripcion='Mi descripcion mas &amp;apos;'/>
```

So basically &amp; get converted to & and then just apos; this wil result in &apos;

[How to write out HTML entity name (&nbsp;, &lt;, &gt;, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427713/how-to-write-out-html-entity-name-nbsp-lt-gt-etc#comment25324634_17427812)

Comment: Hi @Maantje, thanks for answering. I get: <elemento1 descripcion="Mi descripcion mas &amp;apos;"/>, with that change.